# Asyncio python - TypeError: A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python, neo4j, python-asyncio

One of the async function returns the async generator object. I added loop.run_until_complete(func()), but still, it throws the error as "TypeError: A Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required". Below is the code. I'm trying to fetch the records from Neo4j asynchronously. I got the async "Neo4j class from a GitHub. I'm new to this async concept.

```
from concurrent import futures
import neo4j
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
import time
import traceback
import asyncio 

RETRY_WAITS = [0, 1, 4]  # How long to wait after each successive failure.
class Neo4j:
    """Neo4j database API."""
    def __init__(self, config, loop):
        self.config = config        
        self.loop = loop
        self.executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30)
        for retry_wait in RETRY_WAITS:
            try:
                self.init_driver()
                break
            except:
                if retry_wait == RETRY_WAITS[-1]:
                    raise
                else:
                    print('WARNING: retrying to Init DB; err:')
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    time.sleep(retry_wait)  # wait for 0, 1, 3... seconds.

    def init_driver(self):
        auth = basic_auth(self.config['user'], self.config['pass'])
        self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(self.config['url'], auth=auth)

    async def afetch_start(self, query):
        session = self.driver.session(access_mode=neo4j.READ_ACCESS)
        def run():
            return session.run(query).records()
        return session, await self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, run)

    async def afetch_iterate(self, session, iter):
            def iterate():
                try:
                    return next(iter)
                except StopIteration:
                    return None
            while True:
                res = await self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, iterate)
                if res is None:
                    return
                else:
                    yield dict(res)

    async def afetch(self, query):
        for retry_wait in RETRY_WAITS:
            try:
                session, iter = await self.afetch_start(query)
                break
            except (BrokenPipeError, neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable) as e:
                if retry_wait == RETRY_WAITS[-1]:
                    raise
                else:
                    await asyncio.sleep(retry_wait)
                    await self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, self.init_driver)
        async for x in self.afetch_iterate(session, iter):
            yield x

        await self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, session.close)


    async def afetch_one(self, query):
        async for i in self.afetch(query):
            return i
        return None

    async def aexec(self, query):
        async for i in self.afetch(query):
            pass
        return


config={'url':"bolt://localhost",'user':'neo4j','pass':'pwd'}    
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()    
n=Neo4j(config,loop)    
loop.run_until_complete(n.afetch("MATCH(p:Person)-[:Acted_in]->(mv:Movies) RETURN p.name as actors"))
loop.close()
```

**--EDIT**

I have modified the code to work properly. The query returns 218K rows and it takes 5 minutes to extract the complete list and the same async operation in C# completes in just 2 sec. Looks like the above code still doesnt go in async

Comment: That is nowhere near enough information. Please see: [ask], [mcve].

Comment: Apologies. I just uploaded the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what exactly happens without [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I'll take a guess. You probably pass async generator object in a loop, you shouldn't do it. A way to work with async generators is to use `async for`. Here's example:

```
import asyncio


async def func():  # async generator
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3


async def main():
    async for i in func():  # get values from async generator
        print(i)


asyncio.run(main())  # can be used instead of loop.run_until_complete(main())
```